# Validity of application in apple store or iTune store

Tags: ios, iphone-developer-program

Well this might be a really silly question but I am curious to know about validity of application on apple or itune store.

Like if i have a registered developer account and uploaded an application through it. Now developer account is valid for 1 year. And i dont want to renew it after 1 year, so what about the applications that i have uploaded on store? Will they be still available from store? And what about the applications that already downloaded by user from apple store??

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Apple's app store policies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, if your developer membership expires, your apps will no longer be available on App Store. However, your app will continue to function for people who already downloaded it.

As the Apple developer program membership FAQ puts it:

> **What happens to my apps on the App Store if I do not renew my
> membership?**
>
> If your membership expires, your apps will no longer be available for
> purchase and will not appear in search results on the App Store.
> However, if you renew your membership after it has expired, your apps
> will be available for purchase on the App Store within 24 hours. You
> do not need to resubmit your apps.

You can read more from Apple's membership FAQ, here: [Apple Developer Program Renewals FAQ](https://developer.apple.com/support/ios/program-renewals.html)